# ReactJS "TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While running this code I got error on the first line on `App.propTypes`

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined

Code:

```
  class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h3>Array: {this.props.propArray}</h3>
            <h3>Array: {this.props.propBool ? "true" : "false"}</h3>
            <h3>Func: {this.props.propFunc(3)}</h3>
            <h3>Number: {this.props.propNumber}</h3>
            <h3>String: {this.props.propString}</h3>
            <h3>Object: {this.props.propObject.objectName1}</h3>
            <h3>Object: {this.props.propObject.objectName2}</h3>
            <h3>Object: {this.props.propObject.objectName3}</h3>
         </div>
      );
   }
}


App.propTypes = {
   propArray: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired, //I got error over here
   propBool: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
   propFunc: React.PropTypes.func,
   propNumber: React.PropTypes.number,
   propString: React.PropTypes.string,
   propObject: React.PropTypes.object
}

App.defaultProps = {
   propArray: [1,2,3,4,5],
   propBool: true,
   propFunc: function(e){return e},
   propNumber: 1,
   propString: "String value...",

   propObject: {
      objectName1:"objectValue1",
      objectName2: "objectValue2",
      objectName3: "objectValue3"
   }
}
```

I tried to search but I didn't get the correct solution.

Comment: Which version of React are you using?

Comment: Im guessing your on React 16, PropTypes has been moved to another package called prop-types. - https://reactjs.org/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings React version: 16.0.0

Comment: Then, the answers have your solution

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Prop-Types are now a separately maintained library named `prop-types`
Here is the explanation from react-docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

You have to import them as

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class App extends React.Component {
  //App here
}

App.propTypes = {
 propArray: PropTypes.array.isRequired, 
 propBool: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
 propFunc: PropTypes.func,
 propNumber: PropTypes.number,
 propString: PropTypes.string,
 propObject: PropTypes.object
}
```

[NPM Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types)

Comment: i also `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';` but it didnt work

Comment: Yes, same error after adding `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`

Comment: @WilliamKF remove **React** from `App.propTypes`. Your code become `
   propArray: PropTypes.array.isRequired` and do same changes for every where

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
App.propTypes = {
   propArray: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired, //I got error over here
   propBool: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
   propFunc: React.PropTypes.func,
   propNumber: React.PropTypes.number,
   propString: React.PropTypes.string,
   propObject: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

to:

```
App.propTypes = {
  propArray: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  propBool: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  propFunc: PropTypes.func,
  propNumber: PropTypes.number,
  propString: PropTypes.string,
  propObject: PropTypes.object
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

The React package no longer contains PropTypes. You need to install the `prop-types` package and

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Edit: As stated in the first paragraph in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

> React.PropTypes has moved into a different package since React v15.5. Please use the prop-types library instead.

Answer (score 0):

**You should change React.PropTypes.array.* to PropTypes.array.***

```html
App.propTypes = {
   propArray: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
   propBool: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
   propFunc: PropTypes.func,
   propNumber: PropTypes.number,
   propString: PropTypes.string,
   propObject: PropTypes.object,
  headerProp: PropTypes.string,
  contentProp: PropTypes.string
}
App.defaultProps = {
  headerProp: "Header from props...",
  contentProp:"Content from props...",
  propArray: [1,2,3,4,5],
  propBool: true,
  propFunc: function(e){return e},
  propNumber: 1,
  propString: "String value...",

  propObject: {
   objectName1:"objectValue1",
   objectName2: "objectValue2",
   objectName3: "objectValue3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, It can happen in a lot of dependecies which are using React.PropTypes you can resolve this by importing

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
```

and after that change React.PropType to just PropType.It happens because PropType is not default in react anymore you need to import it seperately.

Before
`cards: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,` 
After
`cards: PropTypes.array.isRequired,`

Error I encountered which got resolved when i did this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icbO2.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0yt8.jpg)